# Django, Vue and WebSocket - getting client side to work

Tags: django, vue.js, websocket

There was a similar question on SO about this some time ago, though I tried the answers with no luck.

I am implementing a SPA using Django backend and Vue front end with Vue cli. Django is using channels to send JSON via a WebSocket to the frontend, the frontend receives this data and is supposed to update a table.

The Django part is working. A connection to the WebSocket is confirmed and data is received in Vue, though I have two problems that I have not been able to find a way to solve:

1. The data, while in a variable, is not being shown on the table and
2. The front end only receives the data once - I don't know how to apply a listener to the WebSocket, or in which part of my Vue app, so that new payloads (I hope I am saying that correctly) are received and updated accordingly.

Below I have provided the Django consumers.py file, the Signals.vue view file, and the console.log output showing that the variable does contain the JSON object despite the table remaining blank.

Does anyone have an idea of where I am going wrong and how I can solve problems 1 and 2?
Thanks

**Django consumers.py**

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer


class WSConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

        self.send(json.dumps({
            'id': 1,
            'date': "date",
            'marketOpen': "marketOpen",
            'symbol': "symbol",
            'trade': "trade",
            'bias': "bias",
            'status': "status"
            }))
```

**Signals.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="columns is-multiline">
            <div class="column is-12">
                <h1 class="title"> Signals</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="column is-12">
                <table class="table is-fullwidth">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Market Open</th>
                            <th>Symbol</th>
                            <th>Trade</th>
                            <th>Bias</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr v-for= "signal in signals" v-bind:key="signal.id">
                            <td>{{ signal.date }} </td>
                            <td>{{ signal.marketOpen }} </td>
                            <td>{{ signal.symbol }} </td>
                            <td>{{ signal.trade }} </td>
                            <td>{{ signal.bias }} </td>
                            <td>{{ signal.status }} </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>    
                </table>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Signals',
    data() {
        return {
            signals: [],
            connection: null
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.getSignals()
    },
    methods: {
        getSignals() {
            console.log("Starting connection to websocket")
            this.connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/ws/signals/')
            this.connection.onmessage = (event) => {
                this.signals = event.data
                console.log("Successfully retrieved message from websocket")
                console.log(this.signals)
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**Console**

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS... log.js?1afd

Starting connection to websocket Signals.vue?1d80

Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received. signals:1

Successfully retrieved message from websocket Signals.vue?1d80

{"id": 1, "date": "date", "marketOpen": "marketOpen", "symbol": "symbol", "trade": "trade", "bias": "bias", "status": "status"} Signals.vue?1d80
```

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: Yes - it was only sent once because it was only consumer was only being run once. I setup celery tasks and created a task that would run every x minutes/ hours/ days, etc, this solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send messages asynchronously you should use async,
and write an async function to send data on the requirement, call the send function in view.py or a celery worker, if you want to send periodically celery beat is the way to go else use celery workers for on-demand data.

*It's my first time answering in the stack if there is any mistake in my understanding of question or in my the answer please pardon me. and I am not sure about what is your first question.
(I have just started learning Vue js but I have worked for years on Django so I thought I could answer this as thank you to all people who helped me with responses in Stackoverflow.com)*

**below is a simple example of socket connection I have implemented:**

```
class NotificationConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
async def connect(self):
    # this only exicutes only once when a user gets connected to the socket
    self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
    self.room_group_name = 'notification_%s' % self.room_name

    # Join room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_add(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )

    await self.accept()

async def disconnect(self, close_code):
    # Leave room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )

Receive message from WebSocket
async def receive(self, text_data):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    message = text_data_json['message']
    print(message)
    print("message")

    # Send message to room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        self.room_group_name,
        {
            'type': 'snmpop_message',
            'message': message
        }
    )


async def send_notification(self, event):
    message = json.loads(event['message'])
    print(message)
    # Send message to WebSocket
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(message))
```

#This is how I will send the data on requirement: from any other place:

```
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
    "notification_broadcast",
    {
        'type': 'send_Notification',
        'message': json.dumps(outputdict)
    }
 )
```

if any of you have queries you can reach out to me: amithkhul@gmail.com
Thank you
Amith K